# Allow + in regex email validate email

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Regex is blowing my mind. How can I change this to validate emails with a plus sign? so I can sign up with test+spam@gmail.com

```
if(!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*$/i", $_GET['em'])) {
```

Comment: that regex worked on that email address. did you try it out?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It seems like you aren't really familiar with what your regex is doing currently, which would be a good first step before modifying it. Let's walk through your regex using the email address `john.robert.smith@mail.com` (in each section below, the bolded part is what is matched by that section):

1. `^` is the [start of string
   anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).
   It specifies that any match must
   begin at the beginning of the
   string. If the pattern is not
   anchored, the regex engine can match
   a substring, which is often
   undesired.

   Anchors are zero-width, meaning that
   they do not capture any characters.
2. `[_a-z0-9-]+` is made up of two
   elements, a [character
   class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)
   and a [repetition
   modifer](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html):

   - `[...]` defines a character class, which tells the regex engine,
     *any of these characters are valid matches*. In this case the class
     contains the characters a-z, numbers
     0-9 and the dash and underscore (in
     general, a dash in a character class
     defines a range, so you can use
     `a-z` instead of
     `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`; when
     given as the last character in the
     class, it acts as a literal dash).
   - `+` is a repetition modifier that specifies that the preceding token
     (in this case, the character class)
     can be repeated one or more times.
     There are two other repetition
     operators: `*` matches zero or more
     times; `?` matches exactly zero or
     one times (ie. makes something
     *optional*).

   (captures
   **john**.robert.smith@mail.com)
3. `(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*` again contains a
   repeated character class. It also
   contains a
   [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html),
   and an escaped character:

   - `(...)` defines a group, which allows you to group multiple tokens
     together (in this case, the group
     will be repeated as a
     whole).
     Let's say we wanted to
     match 'abc', zero or more times (ie.
     abcabcabc matches, abcccc doesn't).
     If we tried to use the pattern
     `abc*`, the repetition modifier
     would only apply to the `c`, because
     c is the last token before the
     modifier. In order to get around
     this, we can group abc (`(abc)*`),
     in which case the modifier would
     apply to the entire group, as if it
     was a single token.
   - `\.` specifies a literal dot character. The reason this is needed
     is because `.` is a special
     character in regex, meaning [any
     character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html).
     Since we want to match an actual dot
     character, we need to escape it.

   (captures
   john**.robert.smith**@mail.com)
4. `@` is not a special character in
   regex, so, like all other
   non-special characters, it matches
   literally.

   (captures john.robert.smith**@**mail.com)
5. `[a-z0-9-]+` again defines a repeated character class, like item #2 above.

   (captures john.robert.smith@**mail**.com)
6. `(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*` is almost exactly the same pattern as #3 above.

   (captures john.robert.smith@mail**.com**)
7. `$` is the end of string anchor. It works the same as `^` above, except matches the end of the string.

---

With that in mind, it should be a bit clearer how to add a section with captures a plus segment. As we saw above, `+` is a special character so it has to be escaped. Then, since the + has to be followed by some characters, we can define a character class with the characters we want to match and define its repetition. Finally, we should make the whole group optional because email addresses don't need to have a + segment:

```
(\+[a-z0-9-]+)?
```

When inserted into your regex, it'd look like this:

```
/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*(\+[a-z0-9-]+)?@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*$/i
```

Comment: what about keeping the \. as well? shouldn't it go within the []

Comment: my current regex shows (\.[_a-z0-9-]+), would I have it (\+\.[_a-z0-9-]+ ?

Comment: Ah, so the * mean 0 or more repetitions that pattern?

Comment: Correct, `*` means zero or more repetitions. `?` means zero or one repetition.

Comment: Why isn't the + inside the character class? Did you intend to require [_a-z0-9-] before and after each one?

Comment: That was an awesome explanation! +1

Comment: here is my expression: ^[\w-]+(?:\.[\w\-]+)*(?:\+[\w\-]+)?@(?:[\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,7}$

Comment: This response identifies `myemail@s` as a valid email.

Answer (score 8):

Save your sanity.  Get a pre-made PHP [RFC 822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt) [Email address parser](http://code.iamcal.com/php/rfc822/)

Comment: If I could give you ten +1s I would.

Comment: Here is RFC 822 for JavaScript http://badsyntax.co/post/javascript-email-validation-rfc822

Answer (score 2):

I've used [this regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155#46181) to validate emails, and it works just fine with emails that contain a`+`:

```
/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
```

Comment: This seems nice but it allows other chars that aren't suppose to be in an email address.

Comment: @RickSanchez the sad reality is that regex is not the right tool for parsing/validating email addresses in full.

Answer (score 1):

`\+` will match a literal + sign, but be aware: You still won't be close to matching all possible email addresses according to the RFC spec, because [the actual regex for that is madness](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html). It's almost certainly not worth it; you should use a real email parser for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution (is similar to the solution found by David):

```
//Escaped for .Net
^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+((\\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*|(\\+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$

//Native
^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+((\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*|(\+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the another solution

```
/^[_a-z0-9-+]+(\.[_a-z0-9-+]+)*(\+[a-z0-9-]+)?@[a-z0-9-.]+(\.[a-z0-9]+)$/

or For razor page(@=\u0040)

/^[_a-z0-9-+]+(\.[_a-z0-9-+]+)*(\+[a-z0-9-]+)?\u0040[a-z0-9-.]+(\.[a-z0-9]+)$/
```